# Page pagination always show the first element React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am trying to set up page pagination Material UI in React, but always redirects to page 1 after 1 seconds showing the right element. I use console log and I can see the the slice is changing 0..1, 1..2 and 2..3 but the content is not.

```
  {
    this.state.teams
      .slice((this.state.page - 1) * itemsPerPage, this.state.page * itemsPerPage)
      .map((product,index) => (
     
          <TeamCard
            className={stylesMain.TeamCard}
            number={this.state.teams[index]}
            teamNum={this.state.teamNum[index]}
            verified ={this.state.verified[index]}
          />
     

<Pagination
  color="primary"
  count={Math.ceil(resultLength/1)}
  size="small"
  page={this.state.page}
  onChange={this.handleChange2}
  defaultPage={1}
  showFirstButton
  showLastButton
/>
```

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    teams: [],
    page: 1
  }
}

handleChange2 = (event, value) => {
  this.setState({page: value});
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.getTeams();
}
```

Comment: Please may you make sure the example shared is a [mcve]? At the moment it is not

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `index`. index will be always from `0` to `itemsPerPage`.
So `this.state.teams[index]` will be the elements of page 1.

You need to use `product` on the `map`.

Comment: And how can i get the index of the element in order to access the specific element ?

Comment: And how can i get the index of the element in order to access the specific element ?

Comment: The real index is: this.state.page * itemsPerPage + index